# Find the number of root in interval

Tags: derivatives

Let $f,g : \left[-1, 2\right] \rightarrow R $ be continuous function which are twice differentiable on the interval $\left(-1,2\right)$ . Let the values of $f $ and $g$ at the points $-1,0,2$ be as given in the table as :
[image: Table]
In each of the intervals $ \left(–1, 0\right) $ and $\left(0, 2\right)$ the function $\left(f – 3g\right)''$ never vanishes. Then the correct statement(s)is(are)

$\left(1\right). $$f'\left(x\right) – 3g'\left(x\right ) = 0 $ has exactly three solutions in  $\left(–1, 0\right)$ $\cup  $ $\left(0, 2\right)$

$\left(2\right).$$f'\left(x\right) – 3g'\left(x\right ) = 0 $ has exactly one solutions in  $\left(–1, 0\right)$

$\left(3\right).$$f'\left(x\right) – 3g'\left(x\right ) = 0 $ has exactly one solutions in  $\left(0, 2\right)$

$\left(4\right). $$f'\left(x\right) – 3g'\left(x\right ) = 0 $ has exactly two solutions in  $\left(–1, 0\right)$ and exactly two solution in $\left(0, 2\right)$

My work

$$ h\left(x \right) =f\left(x\right) – 3g\left(x\right )$$
$$ h\left(-1 \right) = 3$$
$$ h\left(0  \right) = 3$$
$$ h\left(2  \right) = 3$$

By Rolle's Theorem

There exist a $c_1$ for which $ h'\left(c_1 \right) =0 $ in $\left( –1, 0 \right)$

There exist a $c_2$ for which $ h'\left(c_2 \right) =0  $ in $\left(0, 2\right)$

How I should proceed further ? Should I also check for second derivative or I can conclude from only first derivative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost done. You know that there is *one* zero of $h'$ in each of $(-1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ -- but if one of these intervals had *more than one* zero, you would be able to apply Rolle's theorem to them and thereby find a zero of $h''$ in one of these intervals -- and you're told explicitly that doesn't exist.

So you can conclude that $h'$ has *exactly* one zero in each of the intervals.

As a bonus, you can also know that $h''(0)=0$, but that is not actually necessary to answer the questions.

Comment: How to get that h''(0)=0

Comment: @AakashKumar: Apply Rolle's theorem to $h'$ between your $c_1$ and $c_2$. This says there must be a zero of $h''$ in $(c_1,c_2)$ -- but you're told there isn't one in $(-1,0)$ and not one in $(0,2)$ either -- so the only place there is left for it to be is at $x=0$.